# WinJS app not showing vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows-10-universal

Hello I am trying to get the vertical scrollbar to appear in a windows 10 app using visual studio.

Steps:

1. Load Visual Studio 2015
2. Select file > new project
3. Choose Javascript > Universal > WinJS App
4. Open index.html modify it like below
5. Run the app

No vertical scrollbar appears.  I have been struggling, can somebody tell me how to get it to work.

Thankyou

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>
    <link href="lib/winjs-4.0.1/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/ui.js"></script>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
    <div style="overflow-y:auto">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var isFirstActivation = true;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand) {
            // TODO: Handle relevant ActivationKinds. For example, if your app can be started by voice commands,
            // this is a good place to decide whether to populate an input field or choose a different initial view.
        }
        else if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            // A Launch activation happens when the user launches your app via the tile
            // or invokes a toast notification by clicking or tapping on the body.
            if (args.detail.arguments) {
                // TODO: If the app supports toasts, use this value from the toast payload to determine where in the app
                // to take the user in response to them invoking a toast notification.
            }
            else if (args.detail.previousExecutionState === activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application had been suspended and was then terminated to reclaim memory.
                // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
                // Note: You may want to record the time when the app was last suspended and only restore state if they've returned after a short period.
            }
        }

        if (!args.detail.prelaunchActivated) {
            // TODO: If prelaunchActivated were true, it would mean the app was prelaunched in the background as an optimization.
            // In that case it would be suspended shortly thereafter.
            // Any long-running operations (like expensive network or disk I/O) or changes to user state which occur at launch
            // should be done here (to avoid doing them in the prelaunch case).
            // Alternatively, this work can be done in a resume or visibilitychanged handler.
        }

        if (isFirstActivation) {
            // TODO: The app was activated and had not been running. Do general startup initialization here.
            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged);
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }

        isFirstActivation = false;
    };

    function onVisibilityChanged(args) {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            // TODO: The app just became visible. This may be a good time to refresh the view.
        }
    }

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state that needs to persist across suspensions here.
        // You might use the WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically saved and restored across suspension.
        // If you need to complete an asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call args.setPromise().
    };

    app.start();

})();
```

whatIAmTryingToDo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>
    <link href="lib/winjs-4.0.1/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/ui.js"></script>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">
    <div style="flex:none;height:50px;background:#000">
        <p style="color:#fff;padding-left:10px">Logo + login</p>
    </div>
    <div style="flex:1;height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:row">
        <div style="flex:none;width:30%;background:#015c1a">
            <div style="background:#006400">
                <div style="height:25px;padding:5px 5px 5px 10px;color:white;font-weight:bold">Activity(0)</div>
            </div>
            <div style="background:#ff6a00;height:90.75%;overflow-y:auto">
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test</p>
                <p>test111111</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex:1;background:#000;margin-bottom:50px;overflow-y:auto">
            <p style="color:#fff;padding-left:10px">Main content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No vertical scrollbar appears. I have been struggling, can somebody tell me how to get it to work.

If you don't set the `Div`'s height, it will expands itself with it's content. So the scrollbar won't show in this case.

So there are two ways to fix the problem:

1. Set the `Div`'s height explicitly:

```html
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:500px">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        ...
</div>
```

2. Use `overflow-y:auto` on `body` tag:

```html
<body class="win-type-body" style="overflow-y:auto;">
    <div>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Elvis.

I've elaborated more on my question with whatIAmTryingToDo.html.  

I need a scrollable left hand pane.  I am still having difficulty however, to get the proportions right for the page.  I have to fudge my height to 90.75% just so I can see the bottom of the scrollbar.  Is there a easy (proper) way of doing this?

If I hit full-screen then the bottom of the pane reflects the top.

Any help would be appreciated.

!DA

Comment: What do you mean by " If I hit full-screen then the bottom of the pane reflects the top"?Could you maybe create a new case on this with some detailed description?